# Software for dubbing

Tags: sound, software-recommendation, video, editor

Is there any Linux software (video editor?) that can do **dubbing** (merge translated audio with video) ?

Comment: You could try separating the audio and video, editing the audio in something like Audacity, and putting them back together using something like Openshot.

Answer (score 0):

The question is old, but still quite relevant. FFMpeg, Openshot and audacity can combine well to do this.

1. Use ffmpeg to split audio and video from a standard mp4 file by using the -an and -vn options to cut out audio and video respectively

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -an outputvideo.mp4 -vn outputaudio.m4a
```

2. Use Audacity to set the outputaudio.m4a and the dubbing side by side to make sure that the lengths and signal levels match and they sync (speech versus background music, for example)
3. Load the outputvideo.mp4 and the dubbing audio track in openshot as separate tracks, sync audio and video and output from openshot into any format desired.